# iPhone . customizing the navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using Xcode template that generates a navigation controller project.

When it starts, the delegate loads the `RootViewController` that has a `NavigationController` on top.

I see a `navigationBar` with a back button.

Now, I am inside `viewDidLoad`.

How in the heaven's name do I customize that `navigationBar`?

Even a simple task of getting rid of the back button is impossible.

What I need is this: to put a `UIView` that covers the entire `navigationBar` area (I will use that to show AdMob/iAds across the whole app)

How do I REALLY access the navigation bar?

Doing this, doesn't work.

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];   
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] intWithFrame: 0,0,320,50];
// put content inside view
[bar adSubview view];
[view release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add a subview to the navbar (the navbar layout its known subview itself to fit the context sizing the titleview depending if it has a back button, leftbtn, rightbtn, etc)

If you need to customize the background, since iOS5 you have a `backgroundView` property

If you don't want to have a back button, simply set the `hidesBackButton` property of the `UINavigationItem` associated to the corresponding UIViewController to YES. *(Can't miss this property in the NavigationItem documentation)*

If you need any other customization, just read the documentation, everything is explained in there. Both in the UINavigationBar & UINavigationItem Class References, but also the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) which explains it all and how each class and components interact to make the NavCtrl work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see or use the navigation bar at all, but want an obnoxious, always-visible advertising bar at the same point in every screen, you could just add your advertising view to the window itself, this will then be on top of your navigation controller and whatever it is presenting.

I dont know if Apple would approve of your design.  I've not used iAds or a lot of apps with them but in my experience they tend to be at the bottom of the screen, not the top - there may be too much potential for accidentally clicking one, particularly with the ios5 notifications.

Comment: OK, but in my case I have to put it on top, because I have a segmented control on the bottom... thanks.